# Lowering kernel timer interrupt frequency

Tags: linux, kernel

When I run my Virtual Machine with Gentoo as guest, I have found that there is considerable overhead coming from tick_periodic function.( this is the function which runs on every timer interrupt).This function updates a global jiffy using write_seqlocks which leads to the overhead.

Here's a grep of HZ and relevant stuff in my config file.

```
sharan013@sitmac4:~$ cat /boot/config | egrep 'HZ|TIME'
# CONFIG_RCU_FAST_NO_HZ is not set
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_250 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_300 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_1000=y
CONFIG_HZ=1000
# CONFIG_MACHZ_WDT is not set
CONFIG_TIMERFD=y
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
CONFIG_X86_CYCLONE_TIMER=y
CONFIG_HPET_TIMER=y
```

Clearly it has set the configuration to 1000, but when I do `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` I get 100 as my timer frequency.So what is my systems timer frequency?

What I want to do is to bring the frequency down to 100,even lower if possible.Although it might effect the interactivity and precision of poll/select and schedulers time slice, I am ready to sacrifice these things for lesser timer interrupt as it will speed up VM.
when I tried to find out what has to be done I read in some place that you can do so by changing in the configuration file, else where I read that adding divider=10 to the boot parameter does the job , else where I read that none of it is needed if you can set the `(CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS)` to acheive low-latency timers even without increasing the timer frequency and the same is possible with a tickless system `CONFIG_NO_HZ`.
I am extermely confused about what is the right approach.
All I want is to bring down the timer interrupt to as low as possible.
Can I know the right way of doing this ?

Thanks,
Sharan

Comment: You'd have to build your own kernel. Grab the vanilla sources from http://www.kernel.org or the source package (not kernel development package, that has just what is needed to build modules against the installed kernel) for your distribution, apply their configuration (if not already done), do a `make menuconfig` to change the HZ value, recompile, install, do a little rain dance, cross your fingers and reboot. Make _sure_ you have a fallback in case the newly compiled kernel explodes.

Comment: With the running kernel's configuration readily available, copying it into the kernel source code tree (I believe as `.config`) and running `make oldconfig` is a good start. Then `make menuconfig` and change the relevant setting, then build as normal.

Comment: Note that you also have `CONFIG_NO_HZ=y` which means that the kernel may not actually run at 1000 Hz unless required for the given workload.